# Time, Place and Speak

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, speech-talking, acronyms

I heard from someone that מזל stands for מקום זמן לשון, (there is a) place (and) time (to) speak. Do you where this idea comes from?

Comment: I've heard this too and I don't know the source but I'm pretty sure that you're interpreting the *'remez'* incorrectly. The idea it's meant to convey is that mazal (luck) depends on those three things: time, place, and how one speaks (and acts; sometimes the ל is said to stand for לעשות)

Comment: i dont know either, but my father always says it!